# Official macOS System security prompt or possible malware? [macOS Catalina]

Tags: macos, security, malware

Why I'm Asking: ***I've used all Apple operating systems since OS X Snow Leopard and I've never seen this security input prompt, or that symbol anywhere on mac's official system security prompts.***

[image: macOS Catalina iMessage Security Prompt]

I'm not asking *IF* being asked is malware. I understand that sometimes macOS will prompt you to sign-in again. The unusual part of this window is I've never seen this style before. Especially the Red "!" logo. It isn't used anywhere I know of when you need to sign back in. In summary, this System Prompt doesn't seem legitimate and it has been spoofed before with malware.

Comment: It's not malware.  [This issue popped up a while back](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7368620) and apparently was fixed with an update.  It's not malware, though.  If you want to be certain it's not malware, delete the account and recreate it in Messages.  I think the password in your keychain somehow got corrupted.